# After meteor update to 1.0.2,the website error with 502 bad gateway

Tags: meteor

I use [this way](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx) to deploy my meteor website on digitalocean. But after update meteor to 1.0.2,the website error with 502. It can run successfully using `meteor deploy`

Comment: You may want to check that you are running the latest node.js version on your deployment, 1.0.2 upgraded to 0.10.33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Meteor Up (mup deploy), make sure you update it to the latest version https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#updating as it will specify a higher NodeJS version. You can also manually set it to be 0.10.33.

For myself, I had to manually update the version on my VPS to Node v 0.10.33, as MUP Setup was not updating it for me.